# What is wrong with ToLowerInvariant()?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

I have the following line of code:

```
var connectionString = configItems.
                Find(item => item.Name.ToLowerInvariant() == "connectionstring");
```

VS 2010 code analysis is telling me the following:

> Warning    7   CA1308 : Microsoft.Globalization : In method ... replace the call to 'string.ToLowerInvariant()' with String.ToUpperInvariant().

Does this mean `ToUpperInvariant()` is more reliable?

Comment: Note, however, that using `string.Equals(item.Name, "connectionstring", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` is probably the best approach in this particular case.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773703/normalization-of-strings-with-string-toupperinvariant

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Google gives a hint pointing to [CA1308: Normalize strings to uppercase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386042.aspx)

It says:

> Strings should be normalized to uppercase. A small group of characters, when they are converted to lowercase, cannot make a round trip. To make a round trip means to convert the characters from one locale to another locale that represents character data differently, and then to accurately retrieve the original characters from the converted characters.

So, yes - ToUpper is more reliable than ToLower.

In the future I suggest googling first - I do that for all those FxCop warnings I get thrown around ;) Helps a lot to read the corresponding documentation ;)

Comment: +1 for "Helps a lot to read the corresponding documentation" (and also for being absolutely correct...)

Comment: Correct, some Polish characters do not make the ToLower() round-trip.

Comment: @ChrisBallance & TomTom Could you provide an example where the round trip failure results in undesired behavior ?

Comment: The 'I suggest googling first' remarks are so annoying and useless. This is the 1st google result.

Comment: I did google it, and I ended up here with the first result

Comment: -1: The rule is silly. The documentation you quoted has omissions. ToUpper is *not* universally more reliable than ToLower. LMGTFY is passé.

Comment: @OhadSchneider: When you normalize user-facing non-ascii strings such as titles, labels or error messages, the only thing that ensues is shits and giggles. The real problems start when you try to normalize identifying strings such as *file names* or *natural keys* that contain international characters.

Comment: googling advice is really helpful

Answer (score 27):

Besides what TomTom says, .net is optimized for string comparison in upper case. So using upper invariant is theoretically faster than lowerinvariant.

This is indeed stated in CLR via C# as pointed out in the comments.
Im not sure if this is of course really true since there is nothing to be found on MSDN about this topic. The string comparison guide on msdn mentions that toupperinvariant and tolowerinvariant are equal and does not prefer the former.

Comment: +1 true. I actually read about that some days ago and was quite surprised that there is a difference. However, I think the difference should be pretty small.

Comment: Any reference to that? Doing .NET 10 years and being qconsidered verygood - I did not know that ;) Would love to have some reference.

Comment: I think I saw that in CLR via C# (J Richter). Still prefer to use an explicit StringComparer though.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with ToLowerInvariant() if that's what your code needs to do.  Sure, it should not be used for string comparison, but that's not ALWAYS what it's for.  I don't like the implementation of this rule (CA1308) in non-comparison scenarios.