# Find a keyword taken from a string and look for it in a list of string

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net

I have a `list` of strings which contain 4 items:

`Orange`
`Lemon`
`Pepper`
`Tomato`

Also, I have a `String str` which has a sentence:

`Today, I ate a tomato and an orange.`

1) How can I check that `str` has some keywords from `list`? without considering upper or lower case letters, basically capturing anything that matches?

I tried this but it doesn't work because it will look for the same words. `list.Contains(str)`

Also `Dim result As String() = list.FindAll(str, Function(s) s.ToLower().Contains(str))` but also didn't work.

2) What if the word `tomato` was `tomatoes` in `str`, how can I still detect the `tomato` part and discard the `es` part?

Any suggestions or ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var list = new string[] { "Orange", "Lemon", "Pepper", "Tomato" };
var str = "Today, I ate a tomato and an orange.";
```

With LINQ and Regular Expressions you can check if string contains any keyword:

```
list.Any(keyword => Regex.IsMatch(str, Regex.Escape(keyword), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
```

Or get matched keywords:

```
var matched = list.Where(keyword =>
                Regex.IsMatch(str, Regex.Escape(keyword), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
// "Orange", "Tomato"
```

BTW this will match both `tomatoes` and `footomato`. If you need to match start of word, then search pattern should be changed a little: `@"(^|\s)" + keyword`

Comment: Don't forget to call Regex.Escape on your keywords. Should you have a keyword with a special Regex character in it, you won't get a runtime exception... So Regex.IsMatch(str, Regex.Escape(keyword)....).

Answer (score 3):

If case sensitivity isn't an issue you could do this:

```
List<string> test = new List<string>();
test.Add("Lemon");
test.Add("Orange");
test.Add("Pepper");
test.Add("Tomato");

string str = "Today, I ate a tomato and an orange.";

foreach (string s in test)
{
      // Or use StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase when cultures are of no issue.
      if (str.IndexOf(s, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) > -1)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Sentence contains word: " + s);
      }
}

Console.Read();
```

Comment: First: IndexOf > -1, 0 can be the first position in the string. Second: Use str.IndexOf(s, StringComparison.IgnoreCase) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, wasn't aware of `CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` :)

Answer (score 2):

```
Regex reg = new Regex("(Orange|lemon|pepper|Tomato)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
MatchCollection mc = reg.Matches("Today, I ate tomatoes and an orange.");
foreach (Match mt in mc)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(mt.Groups[0].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the `list.Contains(str)`, you're checking if that `list` contains that whole string.  What you need to do to check that `str` has words in the `list` is something like this:

```
foreach(var s in list)
{
     if(str.ToLower().Contains(s.ToLower()))
     {
          //do your code here
     }
}
```

That will iterate through your list, and check your `str` to see if it's in there.  It will also solve your question 2.  Since `tomato` is part of `tomatoes`, it will pass that check.  The `ToLower()` portion makes everything lower case, and is commonly used when you want to ignore case.

Comment: Don't use ToLower for string comparisons, use ToUpperInvariant or ToUpper(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) instead. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801508/what-is-wrong-with-tolowerinvariant or use IndexOf(StringComparisonType)>-1 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Function stringContainsOneOfMany(ByVal haystack As String, ByVal needles As String()) As Boolean
    For Each needle In needles
        If haystack.ToLower.Contains(needle.ToLower) Then
            Return True
        End If
    Next
    Return False
End Function
```

to use:

```
    Dim keywords As New List(Of String) From {
        "Orange", "Lemon", "Pepper", "Tomato"}
    Dim str As String = "Today, I ate a tomato and an orange"
    If stringContainsOneOfMany(str, keywords.ToArray) Then
        'do something
    End If
```

Comment: Don't use ToLower for string comparisons, use ToUpperInvariant or ToUpper(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) instead. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801508/what-is-wrong-with-tolowerinvariant or use IndexOf(StringComparisonType)>-1 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
    Dim str As String = "Today, I ate a tomato and an orange"
    Dim sWords As String = "Orange Lemon Pepper Tomato"
    Dim sWordArray() As String = sWords.Split(" ")

    For Each sWord In sWordArray

        If str.ToLower.Contains(sWord.ToLower) Then
            Console.WriteLine(sWord)
        End If

    Next sWord
```

Comment: Don't use ToLower for string comparisons, use ToUpperInvariant or ToUpper(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) instead. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801508/what-is-wrong-with-tolowerinvariant or use IndexOf(StringComparisonType)>-1 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425(v=vs.95).aspx