# How do I compare items inside a List with a substring?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list of string called "markets". I would like to filter markets down to 2 strings: "San Francisco" and "San Jose" just by comparing with a substring (i.e.: "Sa", "San", "san") instead of the exact string. How can you do it?

Here is what  I have, and it only accepts exact strings.

```
List<string> markets = getAllMarkets();

var marketList = new List<string>();
marketList.Add("San");

markets = markets.Where(marketList.Contains);
```

With the code above, markets will have 0 elements since there is no market that is named "San".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To match anything in `marketList`:

```
markets.Where(i => marketList.Any(marketListItem => 
    i.ToLower().Contains(marketListItem.ToLower()));
```

Comment: I have a feeling he wants to add another level to it (searching for each entry in `marketList` and not just "san").

Comment: Jeroen is correct. Instead of passing in a String inside Contains(), I am using a list of Strings.

Comment: @MarloC I believe I've updated with what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you! Although just one more thing before I mark it as THE answer - if I type "san" it does not return anything. How do I make it case-insensitive?

Comment: Ah ok, you want case insensitivity too. Gotcha.

Comment: It gives me an error (...cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47271/discussion-between-mailmanodd-and-marlo-c)

Comment: This is what I got, and it works: markets = markets.Where(m => marketList.Any(marketListItem => marketListItem.ToUpper().Contains(m.ToUpper())));

Comment: @MarloC `ToUpper` is **OK** too,it should give you the correct result

Comment: Actually I think `ToUpper` is proper, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801508/what-is-wrong-with-tolowerinvariant/2801656

Comment: By the way I was wrong.I have checked again,It is `String.Contains` but still it doesn't take `StringComparison` parameter :) @MailmanOdd I guess you mix it with the [String.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c64xh8f9(v=vs.110).aspx) method

Answer (score 1):

```
List<string> markets = getAllMarkets();

var marketList = new List<string>();
marketList.Add("San");

markets = markets.Where(marketList.Contains);

for(int i = 0; i < marketList.Count; i++)
{

    for(int a = 0; a < marketList.Count; a++)
    {
        markets[a] = markets[i].Where(marketList.Contains);
    }
 }
```

Maybe Compare both Lists with for loop? i think i might be missing the point on what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: to make it case insensitive, convert the text in the list to upper or lower case and then compare.

Comment: You may refer to the conversation we're having above. I'm looking for a purely-LINQ solution as it saves lines of code. Appreciate your response!